# Can I convert all the retrieved date from a MySQL query to a QR Code?

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, qr-code

I have a database that contains several tables including one named 'consumer' which has all the data that may relate to a consumer who wants to refuel at a gas station.
I have a webpage where that registered consumer logs in, but what I'm trying to do is once he/she logs in, they end up seeing a QR Code (each has their own) that can be scanned to retrieve all their information stored in the DB. I'm using PHP, any ideas on how I can maybe accomplish this?

Comment: The user who is already logged in would have to then take out their phone and scan the code to see the information that you could just put on the page they're scanning? Or is somebody else scanning the code?

Comment: It seems unlikely that a QR code, which has limited character capacity, can hold 'all' the data a company has on them. It maybe could hold the basics - what exactly are you wanting to hold in the QR code? Incidentally, SO doesn't like answers that recommend libraries etc so you'll probably have to search for a suitable PHP-based library.

Comment: @AlexHowansky replying to your question, the employee at the gas station will scan the qr code to see information such as how much they want to refuel and so on.

Comment: @AHaworth again sorry for the super late reply, basically I stored the user's hashed ID. Then once it's scanned, the gas station employee automatically performs a query to retrieve the latest data entered by that user

Comment: Still confused why you want a QR code. Why can't you just put a link on that page, and clicking the link brings you to the page with all the details you want?

Comment: So, the user logs into the system and gets a QR code on say their phone, and they show it to the gas station employee who scans it to see (I imagine on a screen the user can't see) all sorts of info about that user? ie the company is storing lots of stuff they don't want the user to know about - otherwie the info could be shown on the user's device for the employee to read. Am I understanding or have I got it wrong?

Comment: @AHaworth precisely, except for the last part. All the info stored is entered by the user when he/she registered (so that they could easily log in later on) which is what will be shown on the device of the station's employee.